# How do I import the 'eso-pic' package with PyLaTeX?

Tags: pylatex

I tried to import the 'eso-pic' package with PyLaTeX via:

```
doc.packages.append(Package('eso-pic'))
```

Unfortunately it seems like there a problem with the '-' and I get:

```
\usepackage{eso{-}pic}%
```

This in turn doesn't get correctly imported. How can I fix it?

Comment: I didint' know about PylaTeX, sound nice. I can't find if there's some option to disable that bevahiour https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/latest/pylatex/pylatex.package.html Maybe you should report an issue? https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed looks like a bug.

As a workaround you can add a hardcoded line of code to the preamble of the document using `NoEscape` within `doc.preamble.append`. Note that the argument to this class is the easiest to use with a raw string `r''`.

```python
from pylatex import Document, Package, NoEscape
doc = Document()
doc.packages.append(Package('xcolor'))
doc.preamble.append(NoEscape(r'\usepackage{eso-pic}'))
doc.generate_tex('pypackages')
```

Resulting LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
%
\usepackage{eso-pic}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\end{document}
```